# Long lived LED indicator

Tags: led, oscillator, low-power

I want to have an extremely long-lived (at least one year) blinking LED with a single battery, like one 9V. Think like the battery indicator light in a smoke detector.

The LED doesn't matter to me. Preferably I could use a cheap 5mm one. I have already tried this with a standard 555 timer and LMC555 CMOS timer, the latter lasting longer than the former but both only into a range of several weeks. I also used a modified duty cycle that was well less than 50%. I believe the issue is that any of the 555 timers will draw some power that will eventually drain a 9V well before a year.

A Leona Esaki circuit seems finicky; I can't even get it to work with my current set of transistors.

Comment: A LMC555 has a supply current of 125µA at 9v. 50% duty cycle seems high. And what current are you driving your led at? Off hand, I'm sure a smoke detector alarm is blinking at 0.1 seconds on, 0.9~4.9 seconds off, so 10% to 2% duty cycle, and they aren't powering the led at 20mA.

Comment: A LED at 1mA @ 9V solid on, your looking at a month on. Bring that down to 10% duty cycle, your looking at multiple months.

Comment: As silly as it may seem, a small microcontroller and a low Iq LDO might be the way to go. The MCU can spend most of its time in sleep, and the circuit could continue operating until the 9V drops to ~4V. You ought to be able to get below 5uA for sleep current.

Comment: @tau: Find out what the mAh rating of your battery is and divide by the number of hours in a year. That's your target average mA consumption. Work from there.

Comment: A 9V might have 600mAh capacity, conservatively 500mAh. 500mAh/1yr = 68uA. Well within the capabilities of an MCU with ~1uA sleep/timer current and LDO with ~10uA Iq + 1mA LED at low duty cycle.

Comment: @uint128_t that is an intriguing idea. thanks! btw, does anyone know how commercial products (like my smoke detector example) achieve spans of several years, if not a decade or more?

Answer (score 4):

Do the math.

A LiSOCl2 AA size battery has a capacity of 2400 mAH. A 1mA LED current is equivalent to 8760mAH per year, so your duty-cycle must be lower than 28%. Take 10% to be on the safe side and leave some current for the timing circuit. That means your LED draws an average of 100uA. A simple micro-controller can be made to draw much less (< 1uA).

uint128_t quotes 500mAH cacacity for a 9V block. That's around 1/5 of the LiSOCL2 I would choose, so for the same 1mA the duty-cycle must be ~ 2%. Or take a low-current LED. Test it: is it bright enough for you at 0.1mA?

Did you measure the average current drawn by your C555 circuit? According to the datasheet ~ 0.5mA must be attainable.